# VF pages which is compatible with all objects (standard as well as Custom)

Tags: apex

How to write VF pages which is compatible with all objects (standard as well as Custom) 
what to be included in controller to determine what type of object it is?

How to represent it(object) in VF page?
I have implemented one Controller which represents account object
How to make work that coontroller with all object

Comment: your requirement is kind of broad. what is your aim? if it is just to display, the `<apex:detail>` can do it. otherwise, it would be hard to impossible

Comment: Are you looking for a code resuablility? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4423/any-documentation-on-writing-reusable-code